# mysqld got signal 11 - it's my fault but how do I fix it?

Tags: crash, mysqld

I was copying the database tables from our production server to my dev machine, and in the middle of the transfer I found out users were being locked out of the system because the select had locked a table. So...in my hurry to get the process to stop, I stupidly killed the mysqld process on my dev server.  Now, when I try to restart the service, I get the error below in my mysqld.log. I'm assuming it's because the table file for the table I was writing to is corrupted, but how do I go about getting the service to start again?  I did try moving the table files out of the database directory, but that didn't work (and yes, I put them back after!

```
141223 15:50:29 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
141223 15:50:29 [Warning] '--default-character-set' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--character-set-server' instead.
141223 15:50:29  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
141223 15:50:29  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
141223 15:50:29  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 1 1553165392
20:50:29 UTC - mysqld got signal 11141223 15:50:29 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
141223 15:54:03 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
141223 15:54:03 [Warning] '--default-character-set' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--character-set-server' instead.
141223 15:54:03  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M
141223 15:54:03  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
141223 15:54:03  InnoDB: Started; log sequence number 1 1553165392
20:54:03 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8384512
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 337742 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/libexec/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2e) [0x84c6d3e]
/usr/libexec/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x484) [0x82ec8b4]
[0x9bd400]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
141223 15:54:03 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
```

Answer (score 2):

After a bunch more googling, etc., I finally came upon the solution: http://notesonit.blogspot.hk/2013/05/innodb-unable-to-lock-ibdata1-error-11.html

Comment: Did it really solve your problem?